# excluding log4j from third party jar in pom

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml

I am creating a webservice which hits existing business code.
The required jar which deals with logging is org.ops4j.pax.logging.
I have include this in the pom

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
       <artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This jar allows access to a particular log4j method which is used throughout the business layer

```
LOGGER.debug(object, object);
```

One of the other required jars is a third party jar.
This jar contains a different version of log4j which does not implement the debug(object, object) method.
When I add this jar to the pom, the JVM finds the log4j classes in this third party jar first and the code falls over.

I have tried to exclude the log4j in the third party jar but to no avail.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>        
  <exclusions>      
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that's the only dependency that pulls in the unwanted log4j?  You may need to exclude it from other dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks.
Problem resolved by ignoring third party jar and pulling in dependencies CONTAINED in jar from maven. Ignored log4j dependancy.
Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct answer from https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-classpath-multiple-bindings

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes log4j-core also shows up even after excluding log4j.Below configurations worked for me.

```
<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```